# How to use Drawer inside Modal in ChakraUI

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal, drawer, chakra-ui

So I need to create a design where user can click a button and then a full page Modal component shows up like this:

[image]

There is a blue button inside the Modal that open a drawer like this:

[image]

But I notice that the `DrawerOverlay` component doesn't show. I expect the background to be black or dim. My drawer component look like this:

```
<Drawer placement='right' size='lg' isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <DrawerOverlay 
        bg='blackAlpha.300'
        backdropFilter='blur(10px) hue-rotate(90deg)'
        />
        <DrawerContent py='3vh'>
          <DrawerCloseButton px='3vw'/>
          <DrawerHeader>
          <Text as='b' fontSize='4xl'>
              Tambah Soal
            </Text>
          </DrawerHeader>

          <DrawerBody>
          <AddQuestionForm
             uid={uid}
             roomId={roomId}
            />
          </DrawerBody>
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
```

I try to add some property to `DrawerOverlay` but nothing happen. Can anyone tell, what did I do wrong? Or how to use Drawer with Modal